# Upload to Azure Blob via javascript upload ticket

Tags: javascript, azure, upload, client

I am building an upload tool for our website.  One of the requirements is the ability to store large files into specific azure blobs.  I am running into limitations of Azure Web Apps being able to handle this on the server side.

Is there a way out there to create an upload ticket (similar to vimeo) that our server can create that allows the end user to upload a file, without sharing our azure credentials etc.

Comment: Hi, how's going?Has your issue got resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a shared access signature (SAS) to allow users to upload files from a static HTML page by JS.

For detailed steps, you can just refer to [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser).

I have tested it on my side and it works perfectly for me.

Let me know if you have any more questions.